# Apk installation failed with memory space message despite there is enough memory space

Tags: android, storage, apk

I try to install apk 767kb into android device (smasung galaxi 2) and get error: ".. could not be installed. Free up some space and try again." However when I go to Memory usage I see 215 MB free. Is anybody can explain and advise?
By the way I uninstalled a few applications which definitely hold more memory and it is still not enough.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/3002/where-in-the-file-system-are-applications-installed

Comment: please restart the device, it will work as i faced a problem and restarted the device

Comment: Found the solution. Here it is:
http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/60897/storage-space-running-out-some-system-functions-may-not-work

Comment: That's not a link to a solution. That's a link to loads of other posts. What was the actual solution?